# Event handler of <event> must be added on the initial evaluation of worker script - Firebase Service Worker

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I am trying to register a service worker, and it seems to be working. However, I get 3 warnings:

1. Event handler of 'push' event must be added on the initial evaluation of worker script.
2. Event handler of 'pushsubscriptionchange' event must be added on the initial evaluation of worker script.
3. Event handler of 'notificationclick' event must be added on the initial evaluation of worker script.

I am developing a Flutter Web app, and wanted to secure my firebaseConfig. I noticed that you can view a service worker when in the developer options, so I didn't want to place the config there. I opted for storing my firebaseConfig setup on the cloud, in the google cloud secret manager (for now, anyway).

When the user clicks to "allow" for notifications, I register the service worker, which is the famous firebase-messaging-sw.js. I do this from a async function:

firebase_messaging_manager.js

```
async function registerFCMServiceWorker() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    await navigator.serviceWorker.register('firebase-messaging-sw.js');
  }
}
```

firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
// Event handlers
self.addEventListener('push', (event) => {
  console.log("push called");
});

self.addEventListener('pushsubscriptionchange', (event) => {
  console.log("pushsubscriptionchange called");
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', (event) => {
  console.log("notificationclick called");
});

// Contains the code to run getFirebaseConfig()
importScripts('assets/lib/firebase_options.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.22.0/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.22.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js');

// Initialize Firebase
getFirebaseConfig().then((firebaseConfig) => {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig.result);
  const messaging = firebase.messaging();

  messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
    console.log('Received background message', payload);
  });

});
```

As you can see, all of the mentioned events are at the top of the service worker, but it doesn't seem to matter. I know that the 'notificationclick' event needs to be up there, but I don't even use the other events. If I hard-code the initialization for messaging, the warnings disappear.

I also noticed that the warnings do not point to firebase-messaging-sw.js, they point to a file called register.ts, which is a google file:

[image: register.ts warnings]

```
import {
  Component,
  ComponentContainer,
  ComponentType,
  InstanceFactory
} from '@firebase/component';
import {
  onNotificationClick,
  onPush,
  onSubChange
} from '../listeners/sw-listeners';

import { GetTokenOptions } from '../interfaces/public-types';
import { MessagingInternal } from '@firebase/messaging-interop-types';
import { MessagingService } from '../messaging-service';
import { ServiceWorkerGlobalScope } from '../util/sw-types';
import { _registerComponent, registerVersion } from '@firebase/app';
import { getToken } from '../api/getToken';
import { messageEventListener } from '../listeners/window-listener';

import { name, version } from '../../package.json';

const WindowMessagingFactory: InstanceFactory<'messaging'> = (
  container: ComponentContainer
) => {
  const messaging = new MessagingService(
    container.getProvider('app').getImmediate(),
    container.getProvider('installations-internal').getImmediate(),
    container.getProvider('analytics-internal')
  );

  navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', e =>
    messageEventListener(messaging as MessagingService, e)
  );

  return messaging;
};

const WindowMessagingInternalFactory: InstanceFactory<'messaging-internal'> = (
  container: ComponentContainer
) => {
  const messaging = container
    .getProvider('messaging')
    .getImmediate() as MessagingService;

  const messagingInternal: MessagingInternal = {
    getToken: (options?: GetTokenOptions) => getToken(messaging, options)
  };

  return messagingInternal;
};

declare const self: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope;
const SwMessagingFactory: InstanceFactory<'messaging'> = (
  container: ComponentContainer
) => {
  const messaging = new MessagingService(
    container.getProvider('app').getImmediate(),
    container.getProvider('installations-internal').getImmediate(),
    container.getProvider('analytics-internal')
  );

  self.addEventListener('push', e => {
    e.waitUntil(onPush(e, messaging as MessagingService));
  });
  self.addEventListener('pushsubscriptionchange', e => {
    e.waitUntil(onSubChange(e, messaging as MessagingService));
  });
  self.addEventListener('notificationclick', e => {
    e.waitUntil(onNotificationClick(e));
  });

  return messaging;
};

export function registerMessagingInWindow(): void {
  _registerComponent(
    new Component('messaging', WindowMessagingFactory, ComponentType.PUBLIC)
  );

  _registerComponent(
    new Component(
      'messaging-internal',
      WindowMessagingInternalFactory,
      ComponentType.PRIVATE
    )
  );

  registerVersion(name, version);
  // BUILD_TARGET will be replaced by values like esm5, esm2017, cjs5, etc during the compilation
  registerVersion(name, version, '__BUILD_TARGET__');
}

/**
 * The messaging instance registered in sw is named differently than that of in client. This is
 * because both `registerMessagingInWindow` and `registerMessagingInSw` would be called in
 * `messaging-compat` and component with the same name can only be registered once.
 */
export function registerMessagingInSw(): void {
  _registerComponent(
    new Component('messaging-sw', SwMessagingFactory, ComponentType.PUBLIC)
  );
}
```

Here's the TL/DR section of the code that the warnings point to:

```
declare const self: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope;
const SwMessagingFactory: InstanceFactory<'messaging'> = (
  container: ComponentContainer
) => {
  const messaging = new MessagingService(
    container.getProvider('app').getImmediate(),
    container.getProvider('installations-internal').getImmediate(),
    container.getProvider('analytics-internal')
  );

  self.addEventListener('push', e => {
    e.waitUntil(onPush(e, messaging as MessagingService));
  });
  self.addEventListener('pushsubscriptionchange', e => {
    e.waitUntil(onSubChange(e, messaging as MessagingService));
  });
  self.addEventListener('notificationclick', e => {
    e.waitUntil(onNotificationClick(e));
  });

  return messaging;
};
```

<s>I haven't tested this yet, but a likely solution is to instantiate firebase messaging without any configuration, then update the messaging afterwards.</s> Cannot do this.

**Update** Here are my tests:

1. I tried to load cloud function outside of any event, to instantiate firebase messaging, this did not work (original issue found here)
2. I tried instantiating the messaging without any options/config, but that is not passable.
3. I tried loading data in the "install" event, but result is same as original issue.
4. I tried loading data in the "activate" event, but same issue as above.
5. I tried putting JavaScript variable data in a global scope, but the service worker is in some other scope, so no go there.
6. I tried creating a JavaScript function that would pass data to another JavaScript function, where one was inside the service worker. However, due to the service worker being in a different scope, that didn't work either.
7. ChatGPT convinced me that I could pass configuration data into the service worker when trying to register it, but that didn't work out at all. I couldn't locate any documentation saying so.
8. I converted over to ES6, modular approach. This looked more promising, but in the end I had errors saying my browser wasn't supported. I tried localhost on Chrome, and Edge. Then I uploaded to Firebase Hosting to see if a live app would work, no go there. The browser didn't support it... somehow.
9. I was going to try some localized encryption, but that doesn't really make any sense, since the JavaScript files are visible, plus they would need to handle decryption asynchronously, meaning I would be back to trial #1.

Is there seriously no way to hide the firebaseConfig within a service worker? I can restrict permissions all I want, but I still don't want my key visible.

I have found one of my project's firebase configurations on github, with a HUGE slew of other people's configs. It took a verrry long time to load the minified text document. Just sayin', better to be safe than sorry. Please help me figure this out. I'm a newbie JS coder, and this is a Flutter Web project, so having some tough times here!